# Python custom __init__ not called when imported

Tags: python

I have two files,

```
main.py
options.py
```

main.py is my main program. I import `options.py` via:

```
from options import Options
```

whereas "options" is a class I defined in `options.py`

`Options` has a custom init method:

```
def __int__(self, afc="red", awc="orange", asc="gray", apn=1738):
```

If I try to make an object from within `main.py` like so:

```
options = Options("red","green","blue",1738)
```

Python tells me that there are unexpected arguments. How can I instantiate the object with my custom **init** method?

here is the respective code of my options.py file:

```
class Options:
    anyBarFailureColor = ""
    anyBarWarningColor = ""
    anyBarScrubInProgressColor = ""
    anyBarPortNumber = 0

    def __int__(self, afc="red", awc="orange", asc="gray", apn=1738):
        self.anyBarFailureColor = afc
        self.anyBarWarningColor = awc
        self.anyBarScrubInProgressColor = asc
        self.anyBarPortNumber = apn
```

here is the Python error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/pathToFile/Python/project/main", line 58, in <module>
    start()
  File "/pathToFile/Python/project/main.py", line 55, in start
    options,listOfPools=mapArgs(args)
  File "/pathToFile/Python/project/main.py", line 39, in mapArgs
    options = Options(anyBarFailureColor,anyBarWarningColor,anyBarScrubInProgressColor,anyBarPortNumber)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Comment: can you show us the code from `Options`?

Comment: You should post the code here. Otherwise, it will be very hard to help you.

Comment: It seams you mixed the filenames and/or the import. Didn't you?

Comment: Please post the code and the stack trace of the error

Comment: I modified the question to show code and the traceback. Also, my IDE (PyCharm) already warns me that the parameters after Option( are "unexpected arguments"

Comment: I searched all over the internet for why __init__ isn't taking any arguments. If I have the same class in the same file, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One should neither type ***int*** nor ***index*** and wonder why it isn't working. Sigh. Typo, never was a **init** to begin with. Now everything works.